# YII2 redis cache returns false in terminal

Tags: php, caching, redis, yii2, ratchet

I'm using Yii2-redis cache. I'm trying to set cache in terminal by php command action. This action opens a socket over `localhost:8089`. But I can't set or get some string in cache. Here is my code:

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        Yii::$app->cache->set("info", "something");
        var_dump(Yii::$app->cache->get("info")); //This line
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16 as os and apache2 as webserver and php7.0. I've tested it in another system with the same specification of mine and it's working like charm.

Why the cache returns false?

Comment: Can you show your configuration of this in `main-local.php`?